# Mysql Timestamp difference results

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with a `TIMESTAMP` field (`lastHonored`).

I ran this query:

```
SELECT NOW(), lastHonored, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, lastHonored, NOW()), NOW()-lastHonored 
FROM db.table
```

I get the result:

`NOW()               | lastHonored         | DIFF  | SUBTRACT`

`2014-10-27 14:07:22 | 2014-10-26 19:49:51 | 65851 | 945771`

Where DIFF is the result of the TIMESTAMPDIFF function, and SUBTRACT is the result of the `NOW()-lastHonored` expresssion.

DIFF looks right, but can anyone tell me what `NOW()-lastHonored` calculates? It is not the right order of magnitude, and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would *think* that `NOW()` returns a `datetime` or similar type.  But no.  For some historical reason, `NOW()` returns either a number or a string.  To quote the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
>   or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format, depending on whether the function is used in
>   a string or numeric context. The value is expressed in the current
>   time zone.

That means that `NOW()` gets converted to a value based on its context.  The `-` suggests a numeric context, so `NOW()` is a number whose digits are YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.  My guess is that `lastHonored` gets similarly converted, so the result is the difference between two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can see why by running:

```
SELECT CAST(NOW() AS UNSIGNED), CAST('2014-10-26 19:49:51' AS UNSIGNED);
```

By doing simple subtraction, MySQL is turning both values into numbers. `NOW()` the *DATETIME* becomes `20141027141923`, but `2014-10-26 19:49:51` the *STRING* becomes `2014`.

If you first cast the date to a `DATETIME` it gives you results more along the lines of what you expect:

```
SELECT CAST(NOW() AS UNSIGNED), CAST(CAST('2014-10-26 19:49:51' AS DATETIME) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't subtract dates like you are with `NOW()-lastHonored`. Dates/datetimes are not directly "subtractable":

```
MariaDB [test]> select '2014-10-27 08:18:00' - '2014-10-27 08:17:00';
+-----------------------------------------------+
| '2014-10-27 08:18:00' - '2014-10-27 08:17:00' |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                             0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2014-10-27 08:18:00' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2014-10-27 08:17:00' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the warnings. You'll get results, but they almost always be totally useless/incorrect results, because MySQL is casting the date values as doubles.

Answer (score 0):

They do different things, substraction does not take into account that you are dealing with times.

If you do:

```
SELECT NOW(), lastHonored, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, lastHonored, NOW()) THE_DIFF, NOW()-lastHonored THE_SUBSTRACTION,
NOW()+0 NOW_NUMBER_REPRESNTATION,
lastHonored+0 lastHonored_NUMBER_REPRESENTATION
FROM db.table
```

You will see the numeric difference is represented with the substraction and the time differente with TIMESTAMPDIFF.